# Can you use Storyboards to set auto-layout constraints on the contentView of a CollectionViewCell, as to take advantage of self-sizing cells in iOS 8?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, ios8, xcode6-beta5

I'm using Xcode 6 beta 5 at the moment, eager to try out the **cool self-sizing collection view cells functionality** introduced in iOS 8. It was introduced in the WWDC 2014 session 226: "What's New In Table Views and Collection Views". Links:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/

http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/226

http://blog.indragie.com/

All you gotta do, they said, is that you have to **set auto-layout constraints on the `contentView` of your collection view cell** or implement `sizeThatFits:`. The former sounds easier, so I definitely want to use auto-layout.

When got into Storyboard editor (or IB) though, it appears that you **you cannot access the `contentView` property** of a prototype collection view cell. Is this true?

I did set a few constraints between a label (direct subview of the prototype cell) — I pinned its four edges to the cell's bounds itself, hoping that the label's `intrinsicSize` would provide the needed width for the cell. No avail: I verified that none of these pinning constraints were applied onto the `contentView`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib 
    NSLog(@"%s... contentView.constrants == %@", sel_getName(_cmd), self.contentView.constraints);
}
```

... prints out...

```
awakeFromNib... contentView.constrants == (
)
```

... no matter what constraints I set in Storyboard.

Am I missing something or must I do this auto-layout in code?

Comment: I ended up using Masonry to set it in code by overriding UIView's `updateConstraints`. I would still love to know the answer to this. If you're interested in how to use self-sizing cells check out my demo repo: https://github.com/fatuhoku/iOS-8-Self-Sizing-Collection-View-Cell-Demo/tree/master

Comment: I had to add the minimum height constraint for the contentView in code as well - there seems to be no way to do this in IB... yet. Is somewhat annoying when you're encouraged to use IB for auto-layout, then find you can't for common cases like this.

Comment: Yes I totally agree. As with anything iOS, we do well to get it working. Storyboards has grown up a lot. I guess can't expect it to be perfect all the time. :/